# ¿Qué es el "salario del miedo"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

Leía hace un rato el artículo cuasi hagiográfico [*El camino del guerrero*](http://cultura.elpais.com/cultura/2017/06/17/actualidad/1497736206_768820.html) sobre el torero Iván Fandiño, que murió recientemente por una cornada.

Empieza diciendo:

> “Que se den prisa, que el cuerpo se me escapa”. Así agonizaba Iván Fandiño sobre la arena. Así le confiaba al compañero Thomas Duffau la sensación de abandono. (...) No se lo podía creer Jarocho, plata de ley, **salario del miedo**, contrariado otra vez en las circunstancias de apremiar el traje deshabitado de un compañero exánime.

Donde [*Jarocho*](http://www.purezayemocion.com/noticia/4320/actualidad/el-banderillero-roberto-martin-jarocho-entra-en-la-cuadrilla-de-ivan-fandino.html) es un banderillero que acompañaba a Fandiño.

La parte que destaco es la de *salario del miedo*, pues hasta la fecha nunca la había oído como expresión. Donde lo había oído es para nombra la película clásica [*El salario del miedo*](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film463225.html) (H. G. Clouzot, 1953) y me di cuenta que siempre había asumido ese título sin más, sin pensar que tendría su sentido.

Como el DLE no recoge ninguna acepción relacionada ni en [*miedo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PDGS53g) ni en [*salario*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X1gL4YQ), me puse a rumiar sobre su significado :)

La sinopsis de la película habla de unos trabajadores de una compañía petrolífera que deben transportar un material peligroso. Parece pues que estos comparten suerte con el banderillero: un oficio peligroso, duro, probablemente lo mejor que pueden conseguir. Algo así como el *salario* que obtienen viene en partes iguales *del miedo* a perderlo todo y de morir en cualquier momento.

Generalizaría pues el *salario del miedo* a aquella profesión que se sustenta en una mezcla de necesidad y falta de alternativa. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿Es esta la explicación canónica de la expresión?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buscando, encuentro [este artículo sobre la película](http://www.efeeme.com/el-cine-que-hay-que-ver-el-salario-del-miedo-henri-georges-clouzot-1953/), que abre con la siguiente reseña:

> La cinta de Clouzot es esa expresión vigente y tremebunda de lo que significa vivir atenazados por la incertidumbre en cada segundo de existencia, conscientes de que al siguiente podemos desaparecer fulminados.

Por mi parte no puedo añadir mucho más. Si esta es la interpretación de la película que comparte el autor del articulo que has leído, entonces el sentido de la expresión casi que se explica solo.

Comment: Parece que sí coincide con lo que aparece en el artículo sobre el torero.